# Uvicorn/FastAPI refuses to connect in docker container

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a Uvicorn/FastAPI server that I am attempting to run through a Docker container. The server works fine outside of the Docker container, but when running it through Docker I get a connection refused error when trying to access it using the full hostname. Through Docker it works if I access it through localhost.

Here is my main.py file:

```
import os
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import routers.chat_router as chat_controller
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI(debug=True)

app.include_router(chat_controller.router)

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "https://localhost:3000",
    "https://my.hostname.domain.com:3000"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host=host, port=8000, log_level="debug",
                ssl_keyfile="privateKey2.key", ssl_certfile="certificate2.crt")
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy all the files to the container
COPY . .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118

# define the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 8000

# run the command
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Why is Uvicorn/FastAPI refusing the connection when it is through Docker? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So how are you running the docker container? Are you forwarding any ports with `-p`?

Answer (score 1):

When you are running the docker container use

```
docker run <image-name> -p 8000:8000
```

This maps your docker 8000 port to your host 8000 port 
Then you can go to your browser and go to

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/docs
```

To get your server

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused because I was using Docker through WSL. I needed to set up a port forwarding between my host machine and the WSL ports using netsh:

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8000 connectaddress=172.18.28.x

(change 172.18.28.x to whatever the address of your WSL IP address is)

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150